# Intentionally being struck with batted ball to prevent a double play

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb

Situation as follows:

Runners on first and second, zero or one out. Ground Ball is hit to the shortstop. The runner on second intentionally slides into or kicks the ball, getting himself out, so that the shortstop cannot turn a double play.

Is this legal? Or would the umpire declare the runner at second out as well, a la the new interference at second play. If legal, has this ever happened?

Comment: Interesting concept I had never considered!  Wish I knew answer.

Answer (score 8):

Both the runner who interfered and his teammate (the batter) are out, and any other runners cannot advance.

> 6.01(a)(6):
>
> If, in the judgment of the umpire, a base runner willfully
>   and deliberately interferes with a batted ball or a fielder
>   in the act of fielding a batted ball with the obvious intent
>   to break up a double play, the ball is dead. The umpire
>   shall call the runner out for interference and also call out
>   the batter-runner because of the action of his teammate.
>   In no event may bases be run or runs scored because of
>   such action by a runner

http://mlb.mlb.com/documents/0/4/0/224919040/2017_Official_Baseball_Rules_dbt69t59.pdf